# Building an unencrypted AMI on AWS with packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer

I'm building an own AMI which will be share with several other AWS accounts.
Sharing of AMI seems only to be possible if the AMI is *not* encrypted.
But the default Packer build seems to create an encrypted AMI.

The following setting in the build section of packer.json seems not to help:

`"encrypt_boot": false`

Comment: See https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/10390 . Do you have the `"Always encrypt new EBS volumes"` setting enabled?

Comment: I have been using Packer to create AMIs for years and they have never been encrypted by default. This is a custom AWS setting and unrelated to Packer for sure.

Comment: My thanks to Paolo and Matt Schuchard. 
I wasn't even aware of such an settings, but it seems that's the reason.

Comment: @Dieter I've provided an answer since comments can be deleted over time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will occur if the *Always encrypt new EBS volumes* setting has been enabled in the AWS account.

This is expected, and documented in the [Packer docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/amazon/ebs):

> Please note that if you are using an account with the global "Always encrypt new EBS volumes" option set to true, Packer will be unable to override this setting, and the final image will be encrypted whether you set this value or not.